# should i join gym or not..?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, gym

I am turning 19yr nw and i have an athlete body weighting only 60kg my height is 5.8feet and nw for gaining muscle i am joining gym. my diet is almost good i eat 8 chapatis (Indian bread) per day and some rice, and also drink almost 2 normal glass of milk. i have a fear that by joining gym i will be losing more of my weight and become more thin. And here there is a rule that if u join gym one day u have to do cardio and next day weight lifting.Many people told me that cardio results in losing weight so is this true an if yes what should i do should i follw this rule or should lift every day skiping cardio –  . I want some suggestion from all the experts over here that should i join gym or not..?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: I just want to putup muscles without lossing weight..today it was my trail batch n i cant imagine that from today itself my pants r geeting lose..;-(as today there was cardio batch...

Answer (score 1):

Should you join a gym is honestly too general a question. Lifting and eating significantly will cause you to gain muscle and weight. Cardio can help you lose weight but not if you eat enough so that you gain muscle through cardio. I am 183 cm and about 83 kg (I think that's about 6' 183lbs.)  I also run 5ks fairly regularly and incorporate cardio into my workout at least once a week. It isn't that cardio causes you to lose weight it is just working out a different set of muscles (heart and lungs as well as whatever other muscles you are doing as part of the cardio) If the gym you are looking to join requires cardio look for ways to do cardio and build strength. Jump roping, heavy bag, sprints, and swimming all can increase strength and weight if you eat enough food with them.